# Peltier broke? Or do they just do this?

Tags: heatsink, peltier

I power the peltier on 12v with a heatsink on the hot side

The hot side gets lightly warm and they cold side gets nice and cold except one part, The very top right corner on the cold side is hot, the rest of all the corners (and middle) is cold......is it broke in the right corner or do they just do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Corner of Peltier module is very hot](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/339936/corner-of-peltier-module-is-very-hot)

Comment: Your not supposed to run them without a heatsink, they can overheat.